# Struct not working in Global space for one program but, works for another

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, std

I am relatively new to C++. I recently learned about structures in C++ in the book and it had following code to add measurements in feet and Inches. The code pasted below worked as intended:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Distance {
    int feet;
    float inches;
    };

int main(){
    Distance d1, d3; 
    Distance d2 = { 11, 6.25 }; 
    cout << "\nEnter feet: "; cin >> d1.feet;
    cout << "Enter inches: "; cin >> d1.inches;
    d3.inches = d1.inches + d2.inches; 
    d3.feet = 0; 
    if(d3.inches >= 12.0) 
        {
        d3.inches -= 12.0; 
        d3.feet++;
        }
    d3.feet += d1.feet + d2.feet;


    cout << d1.feet << "\'-" << d1.inches << "\" + ";
    cout << d2.feet << "\'-" << d2.inches << "\" = ";
    cout << d3.feet << "\'-" << d3.inches << "\"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see the structure variable is defined inside the main function while structure is defined outside it.

I also decided to test my knowledge and make a program similar to this which will add time it is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// This function basically calculates how much is carried over to the next quantity for eg. if seconds      //is 122, it will return 2  which will be carried to minutes.



int carry (int inp) {
    int carry;
    carry = inp / 60;
    return carry;
}

struct time {
int hours;
int minutes;
int seconds;
};
    
int main(){

    char ques = 'y';
    time time1, time2, timetot;

    do {
        cout << "Want to add time (y/n) ? : "; cin >> ques;
        if (ques != 'y') break;
        cout << "Hours   : "  ; cin >> time1.hours  ; cout << endl;
        cout << "Minutes : "  ; cin >> time1.minutes; cout << endl;
        cout << "Seconds : "  ; cin >> time1.seconds; cout << endl;
        cout << "Hours   : "  ; cin >> time2.hours  ; cout << endl;
        cout << "Minutes : "  ; cin >> time2.minutes; cout << endl;
        cout << "Seconds : "  ; cin >> time2.seconds; cout << endl;
        
        if (time1.seconds >=60) { time1.minutes += carry(time1.seconds); time1.seconds %= 60; }
        if (time1.minutes >=60) { time1.hours += carry(time1.minutes);   time1.minutes %= 60; }
        if (time2.seconds >=60) { time2.minutes += carry(time2.seconds); time2.seconds %= 60; }
        if (time2.minutes >=60) { time2.hours += carry(time2.minutes);   time2.minutes %= 60; }

        timetot.hours = time1.hours + time2.hours ;
        timetot.minutes = time1.minutes + time2.minutes ;
        timetot.seconds = time1.seconds + time2.seconds ;

        if (time1.seconds >=60) { time1.minutes += carry(time1.seconds); }
        if (time1.minutes >=60) { time1.hours += carry(time1.minutes); }
        if (time2.seconds >=60) { time2.minutes += carry(time2.seconds); }
        if (time2.minutes >=60) { time2.hours += carry(time2.minutes); }

        cout << "Tot Hours"   << timetot.hours   << endl;
        cout << "Tot minutes" << timetot.minutes << endl;
        cout << "Tot seconds" << timetot.seconds << endl;
    }
    while (ques=='y') ;
    return 0;
};
```

Above code generates error that time1, time2, time3 are not defined however, I have clearly defined these structure variables. I also know above code has no syntax error because, when I tried to define structure inside the main() function, the program worked as intended. I am pasting the code as well below:

Since, my compiler was saying he following:

```
addTime.cpp: In function 'int main()':
addTime.cpp:20:9: error: expected ';' before 'time1'
   20 |     time time1, time2, timetot;
      |         ^~~~~~
      |         ;
addTime.cpp:27:40: error: 'time1' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'timeb'?
   27 |         cout << "Hours   : "  ; cin >> time1.hours  ; cout << endl;
      |                                        ^~~~~
      |                                        timeb
addTime.cpp:30:40: error: 'time2' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'timeb'?
   30 |         cout << "Hours   : "  ; cin >> time2.hours  ; cout << endl;
      |                                        ^~~~~
      |                                        timeb
addTime.cpp:39:9: error: 'timetot' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'time_t'?
   39 |         timetot.hours = time1.hours + time2.hours ;
      |         ^~~~~~~
      |         time_t
```

I decided to bring the structure definition inside the scope of main() function and I did this and the code worked. I pasted the code below you can copy paste it in your compiler as well and run it. This is a confirmation that my code has no syntax error. Then, why does the code written in book work and, when I do the same thing, it doesn't work

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// This function basically calculates how much is carried over to the next quantitiy for eg. if seconds //in 122, it will return 2  which will be carried to minutes

int carry (int inp) {
    int carry;
    carry = inp / 60;
    return carry;
};
    
int main(){
    struct time {
        int hours;
        int minutes;
        int seconds;
    };

    char ques = 'y';
    time time1, time2, timetot;

    do {

        cout << "Want to add time (y/n) ? : "; cin >> ques;
        if (ques != 'y') break;

        cout << "Hours   : "  ; cin >> time1.hours  ; cout << endl;
        cout << "Minutes : "  ; cin >> time1.minutes; cout << endl;
        cout << "Seconds : "  ; cin >> time1.seconds; cout << endl;
        cout << "Hours   : "  ; cin >> time2.hours  ; cout << endl;
        cout << "Minutes : "  ; cin >> time2.minutes; cout << endl;
        cout << "Seconds : "  ; cin >> time2.seconds; cout << endl;
        
        if (time1.seconds >=60) { time1.minutes += carry(time1.seconds); time1.seconds %= 60; }
        if (time1.minutes >=60) { time1.hours += carry(time1.minutes);   time1.minutes %= 60; }
        if (time2.seconds >=60) { time2.minutes += carry(time2.seconds); time2.seconds %= 60; }
        if (time2.minutes >=60) { time2.hours += carry(time2.minutes);   time2.minutes %= 60; }

        timetot.hours = time1.hours + time2.hours ;
        timetot.minutes = time1.minutes + time2.minutes ;
        timetot.seconds = time1.seconds + time2.seconds ;

        if (time1.seconds >=60) { time1.minutes += carry(time1.seconds); }
        if (time1.minutes >=60) { time1.hours += carry(time1.minutes); }
        if (time2.seconds >=60) { time2.minutes += carry(time2.seconds); }
        if (time2.minutes >=60) { time2.hours += carry(time2.minutes); }

        cout << "Tot Hours"   << timetot.hours   << endl;
        cout << "Tot minutes" << timetot.minutes << endl;
        cout << "Tot seconds" << timetot.seconds << endl;
    }
    while (ques=='y') ;
    return 0;
};
```

As you can see all I did was to define structure inside the main() function and the program started working. What am I missing? Please help me.

Comment: Remove `using namespace std;`

Comment: ... Because `time` is a library function, so it would, in any event, be wise to use a different name

Comment: Thanks @PaulSanders I learnt it right now but, the hard way. Now, I have significantly improved its functionality of this code with the help of functions